# Проблема с кириллическим запросом к MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, кириллица

Делаю маленькое тестовое задание в облаке Cloud9: нужно на php достать строку из csv-файла, отобрать все до первой табуляции и результат положить в базу. Все чудесно работает, только в базу попадают кракозябры (( Поскольку я даже не новичок, а старшая садиковая группа, то сам не справлюсь. Вот код:

```
<?php

// такая русская локаль указана в /etc/locale.alias виртуальной машины, 
// но setlocale не работает
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"); 

// аналогично не работает (
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("input_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "UTF-8");

// выдает ISO-8859-1 (несмотря на setlocale() вверху)
echo mb_internal_encoding();
echo "\n";

$fp = fopen("test2.csv", "r");
$buffer = fgets($fp);
$date = strstr($buffer, chr(9), true); // обе строки - UTF-8, проверял mb_detect_encoding()

$link = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "password");
$database = "db";
mysql_select_db($database); // у базы тоже кодировка UTF-8

if (!$link)
{
    $error = mysql_error();
    printf("Cannot connect to database\n$error\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Connected to database\n");
}

$query = "INSERT INTO table(field) VALUES('$date')";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result)
{
    $error = mysql_error();
    printf("Cannot insert into database\n$error\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Inserted into database\n");
}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

**P.s.**

"А включаешь - не работает"(с). Строка "12 июля" выглядит так: 12 Ð¸ÑÐ»Ñ

Да, саппорт Cloud9 молчит уже сутки.

Нет, простым импортом csv в mysql нельзя - нужна только первая табуляция (вернее, строка перед ней).

Да, dpkg-reconfigure console-setup делал (там в виртуальной машине стоит ubuntu). Нет, не помогает.

В общем, на вас вся надежда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все заработало, когда в начало скрипта вставил `mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");`

Прошу прощения за беспокойство - это первый, но видимо не единственный нубский вопрос ))

Answer (score 3):

Сразу после установки соединения с СУБД MySQL выполните запрос

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Дело в том, что MySQL преобразует поступающий от клиента текст, если он поступает в кодировке, отличной от кодировки базы данных. Например, создать базу данных в UTF-8, а запросы посылать в кодировке Windows-1251 и MySQL вполне справится с преобразованием кодировки. Однако, чтобы это произошло необходимо либо настроить сервер, либо сообщить MySQL в начале сессии в какой кодировке вы собираетесь посылать данные.

Если MySQL не настраивать, по умолчанию кодировка соединения latin1 (так как родина MySQL - Швеция). Поэтому MySQL пытается преобразовать latin1 в UTF-8 (не смотря на то, что вы передаете ей UTF-8 текст). Ей нужно явно сообщить, что вы собираетесь посылать текст в кодировке UTF-8, чтобы она не осуществляла лишних преобразований.

**UPDATE**

Кроме того, если вы не используете ничего кроме UTF-8, удалите строку

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.ISO-8859-5");
```

Comment: Не помогло (( Пробовал и после mysql_connect, и после mysql_select_database.

Код:

$utfquery = "SET NAMES utf8";
$utf8 = mysql_query($utfquery);

Comment: @AntonFoigt, если не сложно дополните вопрос внешним видом кракозяблов - возможно по ним можно будет понять, что происходит. Кроме того, сообщите пожалуйста в какой кодировке файл test2.csv?

Comment: ...причем кракозябры рождаются еще до коннекта с базой: проверял $date var_dump'ом (как раз перед mysql_connect)- в строке "12 июля" насчитывает 11 символов вместо 8

Comment: @AntonFoigt Ага, а у вас сам скрипт в какой кодировке?

Comment: "12 июля" выглядит так: 12 Ð¸ÑÐ»Ñ. test2.csv - в utf-8. в консоль скрипт все выводит корректно (за исключением количества символов в кириллических строках), а вот в базу кладет черте-что

Comment: @AntonFoigt, тогда вот чего не понимаю, зачем вы ISO-кодировку устанавливаете в начале скрипта setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"); - если ее убрать, сохранить скрипт в UTF-8, что-нибудь меняется?

Comment: скрипт ваяется в виртуальном текстовом редакторе, а в нем нет опции выбора кодировки. Нужно, если я правильно понимаю, правильную кодировку настраивать при помощи функций. Отсюда все эти жесты отчаяния с setlocale и iconv_set_encoding